# How to fix fdisk -u an already existing LVM drive (I broke my LVM)

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, lvm

It's late and in my infinite wisdom I accidentally entered a command into the wrong SSH session and nuked one of my servers.

Before the nuke

```
root@host ~ # fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/nvme1n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xce4852fe

Device         Boot   Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme1n1p1         2048    1050623   1048576   512M 83 Linux
/dev/nvme1n1p2      1050624 1000213167 999162544 476.4G 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/nvme2n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg0-swap: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/vg0-root: 1.8 TiB, 1940507328512 bytes, 3790053376 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

The command I shouldn't have done

```
fdisk -u /dev/nvme1n1p2
```

I selected options

```
n
p
1
t
8e
p
w
```

After the nuke

```
root@host ~ # fdisk -l /dev/nvme1n1p2
Disk /dev/nvme1n1p2: 476.4 GiB, 511571222528 bytes, 999162544 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd4c9e29b

Device           Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme1n1p2p1       2048 999162543 999160496 476.4G 8e Linux LVM
```

```
root@rescue ~ # pvs
  WARNING: Device for PV FbVZOZ-zxwZ-S32P-3L6U-BzkT-fkJ2-UmTDMz not found or rejected by a filter.
  PV           VG  Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/nvme0n1 vg0 lvm2 a--  953.87g    0 
  /dev/nvme2n1 vg0 lvm2 a--  476.94g    0 
  [unknown]    vg0 lvm2 a-m  476.43g    0
```

The server will no longer boot and I am currently in the rescue system.

**How can I add this drive back to the LVM? Is the data on it lost now?**

Answer (score 0):

Okay I did some more searching and I did the following things to fix my issue and all my data is back (as far as I can see).

On my rescue system I did:

```
pvcreate --uuid "FbVZOZ-zxwZ-S32P-3L6U-BzkT-fkJ2-UmTDMz" --restorefile /etc/lvm/archive/vg0_00000-741612506.vg /dev/nvme1n1p2
```

and then rebooted